# How do I pull something other than the str value from a FK relation?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have 2 Models, Client and Service Visit. I have the client as an FK in the ServiceVisit model, and when I loop through the ServiceVisits I can pull all data from the ServiceVisit table but I need to get the associated Clients address and print it but I can't seem to pull the ServiceVisit and work backward to also get the Associated clients address but it just wants to show me the Clients name because that's what I have in the __ str __ on it's model.

Client Model

```
class Client(models.Model):
    #Billing and Shipping Addresses
    address = models.CharField('Address Line 1', max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    address2 = models.CharField('Address Line 2', max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField('City', max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    zipcode = models.CharField('Zip Code', max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField('State', max_length=2, null=True, blank=True, choices=STATE_CHOICES)
    country = models.CharField('Country', max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, default='USA')
```

ServiceVisit Model

```
class ServiceVisit(models.Model): 
    address = models.OneToOneField(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='address', related_name='client_addresses')
    client_id = models.ForeignKey('Client', on_delete=None, null=True, blank=True)
    customer_service_rep = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, to_field='extension', on_delete=None, blank=True, null=True, limit_choices_to= Q( groups__name = 'Customer Service'))
    remove_csr_credit = models.CharField(default="0", max_length=20, choices=ISTRUE)
    driver = models.ForeignKey('Driver', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey('Vehicle', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    #Service Info
    service_date = models.DateField('Date Scheduled', null=True, blank=True)
    first_visit = models.CharField(default="1", max_length=20, choices=ISTRUE)
    projected_weight = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    verified = models.CharField(default="0", max_length=20, choices=ISVERIFIED)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.service_date} - {self.client_id}"
```

Code from the template where it's important to grab the address (filling in the address for google maps)

```
      <i>(Ctrl+Click or Cmd+Click for multiple selection)</i> <br>
      <select multiple id="waypoints" class="rows=20">
          {% for visit in visits %}
            <option value="{{ visit.client_id__address }}">{{visit.client_id}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
      </select>
```

Comment: Maybe you should show your code? Although your assumption is wrong; you *do* get the actual ServiceVisit. Of course, when you *print* that, you get the result of `__str__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need to put trailing `_id` to your foreign keys; Django will do that!

You want to access to the `Client` address from an instance of `ServiceVisit`, So you can simply do this:

```
servicevisit_instance = ServiceVisit.objects.get(pk=1)
print(servicevisit_instance.client_id.address)
```

Also, make sure your `ServiceVisit` instance has a `client` before looking for it's address (as your foreign key field can be blank)

Comment: This is what I needed, so simple and I feel like I looked all over and must have kept missing this solution. I was double underscoring all over the place lol.

Answer (score 0):

```
service_visits = ServiceVisit.objects.all() # query to get all the records for ServiceVisit model

for service_visit in service_visits:
    print(service_visit.client_id.address) # you can get the address of client
```

Comment: Thank you for helping I was doing this but in the template and it was just showing up blank. Using the service_visit.client_id.address got it for me

Comment: Double underscores should only be used in *filtering*, not in field lookup.